# Will exercising decrease the heart lifespan?

Tags: heart

I have heard that the heart, as an organ, has a limited number of heartbeats and by doing exercise you will decrease its lifespan.

I know that exercising itself its healthy for the heart but is it better to do less intensive exercises?

Let's say one's bpm is 130 and other's is 150. Will the second person have a smaller heart lifespan?

Comment: Think about it this way: Training lowers your resting heart rate. You're at rest a lot longer than you're training. So you actually use up less heart beats over the week and therfore live longer. This is of course entierly made up by me and has no scientific basis whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't die because you run out of heartbeats. You run out of heartbeats because you die. Since death is certain, we have a limited number of heartbeats.

But pay attention to the chain of causality.

"The man is from New York, therefore he is from the United States" holds.

"The man is from the United States, therefore he is from New York" does not hold.

So no, your lifespan is not dictated by your bpm.

Comment: ok, I guess I'll go hit the gym now ... no excuses available right now

Comment: Haha, you were using that as an excuse eh? :D Nah, the valid exuses are usually something that's diagnosed by your doctor.